# Extracting a time period changing from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to extract the date cell where the date column starts changing the time frequency. In this case, it's `2021-06-30`. Any suggestion on how to do this in a pandas approach?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2021-07', end='2025-07', freq='Y'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2020-07', end='2021-07', freq='M'))
pd.concat([df2, df1]).reset_index(drop = True)

Answer: 2021-06-30

            0
0  2020-07-31
1  2020-08-31
2  2020-09-30
3  2020-10-31
4  2020-11-30
5  2020-12-31
6  2021-01-31
7  2021-02-28
8  2021-03-31
9  2021-04-30
10 2021-05-31
11 2021-06-30
12 2021-12-31
13 2022-12-31
14 2023-12-31
15 2024-12-31
```

Comment: Does the frequency change only from 'M' to 'Y' or can it be something else as well?

Comment: it only changes from month to year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the frequency is changing from month to year, you can determine the date after which the consecutive difference becomes more than 31 days.

```py
df = pd.concat([df2, df1]).reset_index(drop = True)
df.loc[df[0].diff(1).apply(lambda d: d.days > 31).idxmax()-1]
```

This gives `2021-06-30` as output. `df[0].diff(1)` calculates the difference in consecutive dates, and then we check when the difference becomes more than 31 days. `idxmax()` will return the first date which is more than 31 days far from prev date and therefore we have to decrease it by 1.